# Banco de Dados SQL online apenas para REDE LOCAL, conectar via c#

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, sql-server, winforms

Desenvolvi um sistema para minha empresa e preciso de um banco de dados hospedado na nossa rede interna, explicando melhor quero hospedar esse banco de dados em um PC rodando um Windows Server 2012 aqui na empresa, a nossa conexão é toda cabeada...

É uma rede apenas, tudo LOCAL. Esse sistema foi desenvolvido em Visual C# (C# dot.NET), quero conectar o meu sistema a este banco de dados hospedado na rede local da empresa.

Eu tentei de uma forma: existe pastas compartilhadas na nossa rede, então tentei acessar o banco diretamente apenas com o caminho **(Conexão SQL SERVER via arquivo)** ai ele me retornou um erro dizendo que é necessário configurar um ambiente para este tipo de conexão.

Comment: [Tutorial de como habilitar o IIS.](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh831475.aspx) É a melhor maneira de colocar sua aplicação pra funcionar é pelo IIS!

Comment: Se a tag está correta a aplicação dele é Windows Forms, então o uso do IIS não se aplica a ele.

Comment: Pode colocar exatamente qual foi o erro?

Comment: Seria isso? [Conectando-se a uma instância do SQLServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms162132.aspx)

Comment: Lucas como o Leandro disse é Windows Forms e o uso do IIS não se aplica... Paulo o erro apenas me orientou para configurar um ambiente de instancia e @Shura16 Sim andei pesquisando é a unica forma, mas não deseja deixar ele aberto para conexões externas apenas INTERNAS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há basicamente duas alternativas para o que você quer:

- [Criando um banco de dados LocalDB e fazendo o sistema acessar o arquivo MDF dele](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/vstudio/ms233763(v=vs.110).aspx);
- [Instalando uma instância do SQL Server Express e colocando seu banco de dados nele](http://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx).

A melhor é a segunda. Acessando por arquivo corre o risco de criar colisões caso a aplicação tenha mais do que um usuário simultâneo acessando o sistema.

Comment: Como imaginava teria que instalar uma instancia no micro SERVIDOR da empresa e liberar o acesso local, seria isso?

Comment: @Pedro Sim, exatamente. As versões mais recentes do SQL Server Express não precisam de muita configuração adicional, a nao ser Firewalls e alguma coisa de permissões de rede.

Comment: Beleza  obrigado! Vou tentar instalar no servidor aqui da empresa e apenas liberar acesso INTERNO.